# Postgresql Crosstab with Array row_name

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, postgresql-9.1, crosstab

I have the following SQL statement. The inner query ('SELECT ARRAY...ORDER BY 1,2') works correctly and gives the correct totals for each row_name. When I run the crosstab, the result is incorrect. Changing the 'ORDER BY' in the innner query doesn't seem to change its result, but changes the outer query result. I have verified the types match for crosstab(text,text) for column headings.

```
SELECT
    ct.row_name[1:2] AS zonenumber,
    sum(ct.amount1) AS "sumEmploymentamount",
    sum(ct.amount3) AS "sumExport_Consumersamount"
FROM output.crosstab('
    SELECT
        ARRAY[
            zonenumber::text,
            comTypes.commodity_type_name::text,
            year_run::text
        ] as row_name,
        tab.activity_type_id as attribute,
        amount as value 
    FROM
        output.all_zonalmakeuse_3 tab,
        output.activity_numbers actNums,
        output.activity_types actTypes,
        output.commodity_numbers comNums,
        output.commodity_types comTypes 
    WHERE
        scenario = ''S03''  AND year_run = ''2005'' AND
        amount != ''-Infinity'' AND  moru = ''M'' AND
        actNums.activity_type_id = ActTypes.activity_type_id AND
        tab.activity = actNums.activitynumber AND
        comNums.commodity_type_id = comTypes.commodity_type_id AND
        tab.commodity = comNums.commoditynumber AND 
        (
            comTypes.commodity_type_name =''Financial''OR
            comNums.commodity = ''Financial'' OR
            comTypes.commodity_type_name =''Goods''OR
            comNums.commodity = ''Goods''
        ) AND
        (
            actTypes.activity_type_name =''Employment'' OR
            actNums.activity = ''Employment'' OR
            actTypes.activity_type_name =''Export Consumers'' OR
            actNums.activity = ''Export Consumers''
        )
    ORDER BY 1,2
    '::text, '
    SELECT activity_type_id AS activity
    FROM output.activity_types
    WHERE activity_type_id = 1 OR activity_type_id = 3
    '::text
) ct (row_name text[], amount1 double precision, amount3 double precision)
GROUP BY ct.row_name[1:2]
ORDER BY ct.row_name[1:2]::text;
```

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE activity_numbers
    ("activitynumber" int, "activity" varchar(46), "activity_type_id" int)
;

INSERT INTO activity_numbers
    ("activitynumber", "activity", "activity_type_id")
VALUES
    (0, '"AI01AgMinMan"', 1),
    (1, '"AI02AgMinProd"', 1),
    (2, '"AI03ConMan"', 1),
    (3, '"AI04ConProd"', 1),
    (4, '"AI05MfgMan"', 1),
    (5, '"AI06MfgProd"', 1),
    (6, '"AI07TCUMan"', 1),
    (7, '"AI08TCUProd"', 1),
    (8, '"AI09Whole"', 1),
    (9, '"AI10Retail"', 1),
    (10, '"AI11FIRE"', 1),
    (11, '"AI12PTSci"', 1),
    (12, '"AI13ManServ"', 1),
    (13, '"AI14PBSOff"', 1),
    (14, '"AI15PBSRet"', 1),
    (15, '"AI16PSInd"', 1),
    (16, '"AI17Religion"', 1),
    (17, '"AI18BSOnsite"', 1),
    (18, '"AI19PSOnsite"', 1);

CREATE TABLE activity_types
    ("activity_type_id" int, "activity_type_name" varchar(18))
;

INSERT INTO activity_types
    ("activity_type_id", "activity_type_name")
VALUES
    (1, '"Employment"'),
    (2, '"Households"'),
    (3, '"Export Consumers"')
;

CREATE TABLE commodity_numbers
    ("commoditynumber" int, "commodity" varchar(29), "commodity_type_id" int)
;

INSERT INTO commodity_numbers
    ("commoditynumber", "commodity", "commodity_type_id")
VALUES
    (0, '"CG01AgMinDirection"', 1),
    (1, '"CG02AgMinOutput"', 1),
    (2, '"CG03ConDirection"', 1),
    (3, '"CG04ConOutput"', 1),
    (4, '"CG05MfgDirection"', 1),
    (5, '"CG06MfgOutput"', 1),
    (6, '"CS07TCUDirection"', 2),
    (7, '"CS08TCUOutput"', 2),
    (8, '"CS09WsOutput"', 2),
    (9, '"CS10RetailOutput"', 2),
    (10, '"CS11FIREOutput"', 2),
    (11, '"CS13OthServOutput"', 2),
    (12, '"CS14HealthOutput"', 2),
    (13, '"CS15GSEdOutput"', 2),
    (14, '"CS16HiEdOutput"', 2),
    (15, '"CS17GovOutput"', 2),
    (16, '"CF18TaxReceipts"', 4),
    (17, '"CF19GovSupReceipts"', 4),
    (18, '"CF20InvestReceipts"', 4),
    (19, '"CF21ReturnInvestReceipts"', 4),
    (20, '"CF22CapitalTransferReceipts"', 4)
;

CREATE TABLE commodity_types
    ("commodity_type_id" int, "commodity_type_name" varchar(23))
;

INSERT INTO commodity_types
    ("commodity_type_id", "commodity_type_name")
VALUES
    (1, '"Goods"'),
    (4, '"Financial"')
;

CREATE TABLE all_zonalmakeuse_3
    ("year_run" int, "scenario" varchar(6), "activity" int, "zonenumber" int, "commodity" int, "moru" varchar(3), "amount" numeric, "activity_type_id" int, "commodity_type_id" int)
;

INSERT INTO all_zonalmakeuse_3
    ("year_run", "scenario", "activity", "zonenumber", "commodity", "moru", "amount", "activity_type_id", "commodity_type_id")
VALUES
    (2005, '"C11a"', 0, 1, 0, '"M"', 1752708.30900861, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 0, 3, 0, '"M"', 2785972.97039016, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 0, 4, 0, '"M"', 3847879.45910403, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 1, 1, 1, '"M"', 26154618.3893068, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 1, 3, 1, '"M"', 1663.49609248196, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 1, 4, 1, '"M"', 91727.9065950723, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 1, 1, 5, '"M"', 855899.319689473, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 1, 3, 5, '"M"', 54.4372375336784, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 1, 4, 5, '"M"', 3001.75868302327, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 2, 1, 2, '"M"', 150885191.664482, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 2, 2, 2, '"M"', 99242746.1181359, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 2, 3, 2, '"M"', 90993266.1879518, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 2, 4, 2, '"M"', 60169908.2975819, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 3, 1, 3, '"M"', 642982844.104623, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 3, 2, 3, '"M"', 421379496.576106, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 3, 3, 3, '"M"', 592125233.320609, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 3, 4, 3, '"M"', 400206994.693349, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 4, 1, 4, '"M"', 449206658.578704, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 4, 2, 4, '"M"', 103823580.173348, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 4, 3, 4, '"M"', 181300924.388112, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 4, 4, 4, '"M"', 143113096.547075, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 5, 1, 1, '"M"', 83889.8852772168, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 5, 2, 1, '"M"', 25716.5837854808, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 5, 3, 1, '"M"', 10243.7021847824, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 5, 4, 1, '"M"', 22406.3296935502, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 5, 1, 5, '"M"', 408669650.696034, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 5, 2, 5, '"M"', 125278360.769936, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 5, 3, 5, '"M"', 49902204.2985933, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 5, 4, 5, '"M"', 109152455.018677, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 5, 1, 20, '"M"', 161822.743734245, 1, 4),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 5, 2, 20, '"M"', 49607.031096612, 1, 4),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 5, 3, 20, '"M"', 19759.998336631, 1, 4),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 5, 4, 20, '"M"', 43221.5842952059, 1, 4),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 7, 1, 1, '"M"', 122316.017730318, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 7, 2, 1, '"M"', 20514.5008361246, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 7, 3, 1, '"M"', 8431.33094615992, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 7, 4, 1, '"M"', 75842.631567318, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 13, 1, 5, '"M"', 1195626.97941868, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 13, 2, 5, '"M"', 567002.352487648, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 13, 3, 5, '"M"', 1104908.87426762, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 13, 4, 5, '"M"', 1071325.74253601, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 17, 1, 1, '"M"', 751648.370711072, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 17, 2, 1, '"M"', 340439.936040081, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 17, 3, 1, '"M"', 800477.767008582, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 17, 4, 1, '"M"', 489745.223392316, 1, 1),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 17, 1, 20, '"M"', 3154907.39011312, 1, 4),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 17, 2, 20, '"M"', 1428934.74123601, 1, 4),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 17, 3, 20, '"M"', 3359859.9041298, 1, 4),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 17, 4, 20, '"M"', 2055616.54193613, 1, 4),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 18, 1, 20, '"M"', 2088003.66854949, 1, 4),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 18, 2, 20, '"M"', 1310122.52506653, 1, 4),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 18, 3, 20, '"M"', 1481450.29636847, 1, 4),
    (2005, '"C11a"', 18, 4, 20, '"M"', 3035710.53213605, 1, 4)
;
```

I have manipulated the query in several ways (changed type casting, order by, etc), but always get incorrect values. The row and column headers are at least consistently correct.

Comment: I think we'd need sample data to have any hope of helping you with this. http://sqlfiddle.com/ please.

Comment: It seems sqlfiddle doesn't support crosstab(). I could post the create table code from the fiddle if I don't figure things out today.

Comment: Yeah - create table and some data inserts are the important bit